# Error connecting ibm db2 on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, db2

I've been trying to connect to the IBM DB2 server hosted on IBM cloud using the provided credentials. I followed the instruction but i received following error :

```
!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9
!pip install ibm_db_sa
!pip install ipython-sql
%load_ext sql
%sql ibm_db_sa://...
```

> (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004\r SQLCODE=-1042
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
> postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
> or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

when I tried to upgrade my dependencies:

```
!pip install --upgrade ibm_db
!pip install --upgrade ibm_db_sa
!pip install --upgrade SQLAlchemy

import ibm_db
import ibm_db_sa
import sqlalchemy

%load_ext sql
%sql ibm_db_sa://...
```

I got this error:

> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
> postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
> or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
> 'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict.immutabledict' object does not support item deletion
> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
> postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
> or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

How to fix this SQLAlchemy connection problem?
I have tried everything even with setting **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** and **LYLD_LIBRARY_PATH** like some other solutions recommends.

Comment: please edit your question (do not use comments) to add missing information (1) your operating system name+version (2) the connection string (remove the userid, password values) showing whether you are using SSL/TLS or not and (3) whether you have tried connecting to the database outside of python (for example, via either db2cli command, or via jdbc)